# making connection between lua files

Tags: lua, connection, coronasdk, require

I have the `main.lua` and the `play.lua`. this is the `play.lua`: (if I have things to improve in the code please tell me)

```
local play = {}

play.create = function (  )  
--not important
end

return play
```

**main.lua**

```
physics = require('physics')
physics.start()
local play = require( "play" )
play.create()
```

If I'm printing it `print(play)` it writes  "true". If I'm printing physics `print(physics)` it writes "table: ..number.."
so why play is Boolean?
what is the problem?

I copied the whole code from "play.lua" to "main.lua" and it is wirking. and when I print it in writes `print(play)` it writes "table ..number..".

maybe I opend the play file Incorrectly? I opened new file and save it as .lua

Comment: Are you sure your `play` file is being loaded correctly and not some other file/module?

Comment: @EtanReisner's suggestion should be easy enough to debug with stepping or a breakpoint, or even `print("play loaded")` in "play.lua".

Comment: I dont know what is "stepping" and "breakpoint"/can you explain please?

Comment: There a various debugging techniques. The simplest is to trace using `print` statements. [IDEs](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaIntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) can support breaking into the code where you can see what code is being executed and the values of variables at that point. Breaks can be set on specific lines or can occur in step fashion on the next line. Try [Zero Brane](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging) (especially since you are using Corona) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/ldt/) (especially if you are familiar with Java).